# Typedef and enum with same name?

Tags: c, enums, typedef, freeimage

In the library [FreeImagePlus](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), in [`FreeImage.h`](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fip/FreeImage_8h_source.html), there is a funny `#define` which seems to create a `typedef` and an `enum` with the same name:

```
#define FI_ENUM(x)      typedef int x; enum x
```

This is expanded by the preprocessor to code like:

```
typedef int FREE_IMAGE_FILTER;
enum FREE_IMAGE_FILTER {
 FILTER_BOX = 0,
 FILTER_BICUBIC = 1,
[...]
```

What does this do? Is it even legal to have a `typedef` and an `enum` with the same name?
And isn't an `enum` compatible to `int` anyway? Why does FreeImage do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Names of structures, unions and enumerations lives in their own namespace. That's why you can declare a `struct`/`union`/`enum` variable with the same name as the actual `struct`/`union`/`enum`.

And it's not the name of the complete `enum` (e.g. for `enum X` I mean the `X`) that has to be compatible with an integer, it's the names *inside* the enumeration.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the namespaces. Still, where does the "typedef int" help? Is there any code which breaks without it?

Comment: @sleske In general it's not needed, you might as well do `typedef enum X { ... } X;` Unless there are operations on variables of type `X` that can't be done on enumeration types.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [C99 N1256 draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.2.1 "Scopes of identifiers":

> An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter.

which means that in:

```
typedef int id;
```

`id` is an identifier.

And from 6.2.3 "Name spaces of identifiers":

BEGIN QUOTE

If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:

- label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
- the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
- the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member via the . or -> operator);
- all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

END QUOTE

So in:

```
typedef int id;
enum id {ID0};
```

- the first `id` is an ordinary identifier
- the second is a tag identifier

an both can coexist pacifically.

On the other hand, we could not do something like:

```
typedef int id;
int id;
```

because both would be ordinary identifiers.